# public definition of GetEnumerator in asp.net mvc missing?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2

Should I manually create a definition for GetEnumerator? Seems like it should know...

I get the following error:

> foreach statement cannot operate on
>   variables of type
>   'MvcAppNorthwind.Models.Product'
>   because
>   'MvcAppNorthwind.Models.Product' does
>   not contain a public definition for
>   'GetEnumerator'

```
Line 9:      <h2><%: ViewData["Message"] %></h2>
Line 10:     <ul>
Line 11:     <% foreach (MvcAppNorthwind.Models.Product p in ViewData.Model)  {   %>
Line 12:     <li><%= p.ProductName %></li>
Line 13:     <% } %>
```

In my controller I have this code:

```
  NorthwindDataContext db = new NorthwindDataContext(); 

    ViewData["Message"] = "Welcome to ASP.NET MVC!";
    var products = from p in db.Products
                   select p; 


    return View(products);
```

I changed the declaration in my view like this and now it works:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/Shared/Site.Master" Inherits="System.Web.Mvc.ViewPage<IEnumerable<MvcAppNorthwind.Models.Product>>" %>
```

**But if you want to display or use data from several models in the same view? How do you do it then?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change the type of "products" from var to IEnumerable`<MvcAppNorthwind.Models.Product`> and make sure your cast reflects the same.

In answer to your last question, you could assign objects to a dictionary item in ViewData OR better yet you could create a View Model that contains all of the data that you need for the view. That way you have better separation of concerns by having a model that is specific for your view.